# Logistic regression odds vs Survival analysis odds

Tags: logistic, survival, odds-ratio

Why do I get significantly different answers from the logistic regression and survival analyses? How can I fix this code?

Logistic regression:

```
logit1 <- glm(Hospitalization~ Age+Sex+Race_cat+Condition+Tobaco_Use+previous.positive+Vaccination_Category, data = dataset_D,family = "binomial")

 status.top                                                                                              
top.headers "Vaccination Protection" "# of Individuals" "# Hospitalization (%)" "Adjusted Protection: Odds (95% CI)"
            "Unvaccinated"           "304326"           "1228 (0.4%)"           "Reference"                         
            "Fully Vaccinated"       "189331"           "50 (0%)"               "94.7 (93.0-96.0)"
```

Survival analysis:

```
dataset_D$survival.time = as.numeric((dataset_D$Hos_Admitted_Date )- date.start)
dataset_D$survival.time = ifelse(is.na(dataset_D$survival.time )== T|dataset_D$survival.time==0|dataset_D$survival.time<0,0.5,dataset_D$survival.time) 

    
out1 = coxph(Surv(survival.time,Hospitalization) ~  Age+Sex+Race_cat+Condition+Tobaco_Use+previous.positive+Vaccination_Category,data=dataset_D)

 status.top                                                                                              
top.headers "Vaccination Protection" "# of Individuals" "# Hospitalization (%)" "Adjusted Protection: Odds (95% CI)"
            "Unvaccinated"           "304326"           "1228 (0.4%)"           "Reference"                         
            "Fully Vaccinated"       "189331"           "50 (0%)"               "57.6 (43.6-68.2)"
```

Comment: While the formatting of your question makes it very difficult to make out what's going on, a big difference between the two analyses is that survival accounts for the *time to* event. In logistic regression, unless you apply an offset, there is no adjustment for different follow-up times.

Answer (score 3):

Logistic regression and survival analysis are different statistical methods designed to answer different types of questions. The fact that you're getting  different results is not surprising, as these methods assess relationships between variables in different ways.

Logistic regression is used to model the probability of an event occurring at **any point** during the study period. It does not take into account the time to the event. Survival analysis, on the other hand, handles **time-to-event** data. It accounts for both the occurrence of the event and the time at which the event occurs. This is particularly important when the risk of the event changes over time.